# serialization format for arrays in R, python/numpy/scipy, C++, matlab

Tags: matlab, serialization

What is the best format for serializing data in all these languages. "Best" means most support for libraries. My answer so far in the .mat format (from matlab). I am also mostly caring about writing from C++ and reading into scripting languages. I care less about the other way around for now.

Boost has various serialization routines but I don't think they are well supported across all the useful scripting languages with good math and plotting support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html).  If you poke about the web you'll find bindings to all of the languages you mention.  The Matlab `.mat` format is, under the hood, HDF5.